# Decomposition of a maximal ideal as a union of smaller prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $K$ be a field, $S=K[X,Y]$ the polynomial ring in two variables and consider the ideal $M=\langle X,Y\rangle$ (ideal generated by $X$ and $Y$). Show that $M$ is a union of strictly smaller prime ideals.

Comment: what is "smaller" prime ideals?

Comment: at list it is not **finite** union of strictly smaller prime ideals:  > If $M$ is a finite union of   strictly smaller prime ideals then by [Prime Avoidance  Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_avoidance_lemma), $M$ must be subset of one of them. but $M$ is maximal. so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** The height one prime ideals in $K[X,Y]$ are principal and generated by irreducible polynomials.

> We have $$(X,Y)=\bigcup_{p\ \text{irreducible},\ p(0,0)=0}(p).$$